# Is it possible to have a Shortcut in Windows Metro Start Menu but not in Classic Start Menu?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

On my Laptop I am using Windows 8.1 and Classic Start Menu. Is it possible to add a shortcut to the Windows Metro Start Menu without having it in Classic Start Menu?

That perhaps means, without a Shortcut inside "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\S tart Menu\".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Place the shortcut in one of the folders under:

```
%localappdata%\microsoft\windows\application shortcuts\<subfolder>
```

Then right-click on the shortcut and click `Pin to Start`.

The Start screen would show the shortcut but Classic Start Menu wouldn't.